# Input Range Slider JQueryMobile Remove valuefield from view

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, slider, range

Is there a way to remove the valuefield in the range slider jquerymobile plugin?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/forms/forms-slider.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood completely...  Here is the answer to your question which makes so much more sense now that I've reread it. :P

Just apply the following css rule:

```
input.ui-slider-input {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I figured out a styling way, just set margin-left:-55px;, i know its a  lazy way, but for common purposes, it worked. Do you have a better way?

Comment: @Berti wait a second... do you mean removing the input box from view?

Comment: @Berti ... sorry... I totally misunderstood you.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Downloaded the css jqmobile file and searched for the "input.ui-slider-input" did the edit and worked. Thanks!