# Disabling jquery mobile slider counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to take the current value indicator off the jquery mobile slider. How would I do this?

Comment: show what you have done so far: your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406304/input-range-slider-jquerymobile-remove-valuefield-from-view

Comment: `.ui-slider-input { display: none!important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/slider/options.html

Sets the default state of the slider to disabled when "true".

```
$('.selector').slider({ disabled: "true" });
```